# Finding sum of convergent infinite sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For the following series: 
$\sum_{i=1}^∞  \frac{(4i+6)}{i^3+3i^2+2i}$
I have determined that the limit is 0, and therefore the series is convergent. How do I go about finding the sum of this infinite series?

Comment: While this series does indeed converge, the fact that "the limit is zero" is not sufficient to deduce this.

Comment: How would you suggest I prove the convergence of the series?

Comment: Show that there is $C>0$ such that $\frac{4i+6}{i^3+3i^2+2i}\le\frac{C}{i^2}$ and use the compariosn test.

Comment: Are you supposed to know about harmonic numbers ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

$$\frac{4x + 6}{x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x} = \frac{3}{x} - \frac{2}{x+1} - \frac{1}{x+2}$$

If you find the sum of the first $n$ terms using the above decomposition, some cancellation occurs to give you the sum of the first $n$ terms in terms of a rational function of $n$.

Comment: Once you break it down to this, these individual terms are harmonic, right? Therefore, would the series be divergent?

Comment: @Hvb123 They are harmonic, but the entire series isn't exactly a harmonic series. Try writting out the first few terms and notice the cancellations that occur.